# How to add custom task status to mermaid gantt chart?

Tags: javascript, mermaid

I need to add the "review" and "devtest" task status with some special color to my mermaid gantt chart. How can I do this?

I use pure javascript version

I want to make it work something like this:

```
gantt
    title A Gantt Diagram
    dateFormat  YYYY-MM-DD

    section Section
    A task            :active, a1, 2014-01-01, 3d
    another task0     :review, after a1  , 2d
    another task      :devetest, 2d
    section Another
    Task in sec       :done, 2014-01-12  , 1d
    another task1     :active,crit, 2d
    another task2     :review,crit, 3d
    another task3     :devtest,crit, 4d
    another task3     :done,crit, 2d
    another task4     :crit, 1d
    another task5     : 6d
```